# Can I ask same question again if nobody has answered?

Tags: support, questions, reposts

Can I ask same question again if nobody has answered it for some days?
Or is there way to re-post a question after some predefined waiting period?

Comment: What would give you the impression that you could do such a thing?

Comment: question  might be missed by some experts so if i re-ask ,those people may get it again and I get answer

Comment: Why would they be any more likely to see it if you re-ask? Most of the experts monitor questions by their tags. It doesn't matter when you posted it.

Comment: Can you see the link that @Mark has given you in his comment?  If you read there - you should get all the answers you need.  Its quite fitting that you ask this question about post duplication when there is a duplicate already out there to your own question :)

Comment: Also related - [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)

Answer (score 9):

Absolutely **not**.

What you are talking about it posting a duplicate (and even worse - knowingly).
You should never do this.  If there is a question and you really would like to get an answer - you could place a bounty on that post to attract more attention.

Another option would be (if it is your own post) is to continually update it with more information as you continue to research the problem.  This will "bump" your post to the top of the active question list.

**Be assured that If you *do* re-post a question it will be swiftly closed as a duplicate.**

---

Sometimes a question is not answered because someone has yet to find it to be interesting enough to take the time to solve.  Sometimes the question demands some heavy research/testing and people simply do not have all the free time necessary to dedicate to solving the issue.  Remember that nobody gets paid to answer questions on Stack Overflow - people do it out of their own generosity/curiosity.  You won't be able to force someone to answer a post.

All you can do is make the post -

- Ascetically pleasing and correctly formatted (easy to read).  <sub>Lists... lists... lists...</sub>
- Concise - no rambling (easy to understand)
- Accurate (accurately describes the OP's problem)

And make yourself :

- **Available to follow up questions** (if someone wants to clarify something before attempting to answer it is always helpful if the OP is around to give some further explinations)

  - Sometimes all you need to answer a post is 2mins of the OP's time to fully understand what they need.
- **Patient!** Like I said - people are helping you for free - you can't rush them.
- Open to criticism - writing a perfect post is **HARD**!  Be open to suggestions from others on how to improve your post.

  - It might be in the form of a request for more information/code samples etc... If someone took the time to give you some **constructive criticism** - consider it.